# View from layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, view, android-layout

I have a Finger paint program that I copied from the androids API demo, I have Changed it a little bit and want to call from an xml file that is calling the view instead of calling the view straight into the main Java. I have made a new class for MyView.java instead of having it directly inside of the main java file so that I can call it into the xml. Now the MyView.java is set to `extends View` and I have my xml that is holding the view set to `my.project.MyView`. and my `setContentView` inside of my main java, is set to `setContentView(R.layout.main)`. I am getting a FC when I try to run the program. Am I not able to do this? Should MyView be set to `extends SurfaceView`?
**Main XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<my.project.MyView
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyView.java:**

```
public class MyView extends View {

private static final String TAG = "MyApp"; 

private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

private Paint       mPaint;

public MyView(Context c, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(c, attr);
    //**size of drawing area.**\\
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480,650, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

  try{
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
   }catch(Exception exception){
      Log.d(TAG, "mPath=" + mPath + ", mPaint=" + mPaint);
   }

}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

**MyMain java:**

```
public class MyMain extends GraphicsActivity
    implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {    

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

**Log Cat:**

```
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPath(Canvas.java:950)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at www.hotapp.com.thepatch.html.MyView.onDraw(MyView.java:42)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-05 09:26:30.668: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8104):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Line 42**

```
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

**EDIT**

I put

```
try{
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
   }catch(Exception exception){
      Log.d(TAG, "mPath=" + mPath + ", mPaint=" + mPaint);
   }
```

In my log cat I came up with

```
 05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPath(Canvas.java:950)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at www.hotapp.com.thepatch.html.MyView.touch_up(MyView.java:75)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at www.hotapp.com.thepatch.html.MyView.onTouchEvent(MyView.java:95)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-05 10:15:03.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8596):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is my touch_up**

```
private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}
```

**Line 75 of the touch_up:**

```
 // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

**my onTouchEvent**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Line 95 onTouchEvent**

```
touch_up();
```

Also the program starts up now, but as soon as I touch the screen I get a FC.
-Thanks

Comment: As usual with FC, logcat would be helpful.

Comment: Post your onDraw method, as this is where the Force Close comes from.

Comment: @ColdForged I have added my Log cat.

Comment: @dmon The full onDraw method has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was so simple. Inside of my `MyView.Java` I had `private Paint mPaint` and `private Paint mBitmapPaint` which was conflicting so I took out`private Paint mPaint` and the program worked great. Thank you everyone for the help you have given me.

Answer (score 1):

Just an initial hunch, but to start with your custom view constructor must also have, at least, the AttributeSet field.

```
public class MyView extends View {
..............
..............
  public MyView(Context c, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(c, attr);
    ..............
    ..............
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, and it is correct to extend `View`, it is how you create custom views.

As LogCat shows, your error is caused by the `onDraw` method of your custom class - something in there is null

`java.lang.NullPointerException` at `www.hotapp.com.thepatch.html.MyView.onDraw(MyView.java:42)`

Comment: @Joseph Earl line 42 of MyView is `canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);` im not sure were the its saying its null or not.

Comment: @Joseph Earl Would I just add the log statement into the onDraw() function... sorry I am new to the log cat and logging stuff.

Comment: Yes add a `Log.d("SOME_TAG", "onDraw: mPath=" + mPath + ", mPaint=" + mPaint);` just before you call `canvas.drawPath`. The `SOME_TAG` can be anything, usually the name of the class is used so it is easy to tell things apart.

Comment: @Joseph Earl Edits have been added above.

Comment: Could you post the full code to MyView.java if it is not too large?

Comment: @Joseph Earl MyView.java added